# Cinnamon, Stuck with 'old style' menu

Tags: cinnamon

I tried installing nvidia drivers, but that didn't work, so I reverted to the nouveau ones. Everything is almost back to normal except my cinnamon menu is looking strange (and I can't do things like open the menu with the 'windows' key).

What I have:

[image: Current old style menu]

What I had before, and what I want:

[image: Previous better menu]

Opening up cinnamon settings and changing the theme does nothing, I've also tried sudo apt-get install --reinstall cinnamon to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running Linux Mint, so I was unsure whether to post this in Ask Ubuntu or the general Unix StackExchange. I ended up posting here because I don't have enough reputation in the Unix StackExchange to post pictures.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the panel and choose add applet . In the windows , either look for "cinnamon menu" or simply click on restore to default at the bottom. That should be sufficient

Comment: Right clicking on the panel does nothing (if I right click on an applet I get 'about')

Comment: so launch cinnamon-settings then go to applets

Comment: Cinnamon Menu is already ticked.

Comment: did you try to restore to default ?

Comment: On the Cinnamon Settings - Applets? Yes

Comment: (Also, trying to change Cinnamon Themes from the Cinnamon Settings doesn't have any effect)

Comment: Have you checked if there is any other menu applet in the list ? like a "classic menu" or something ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7135/discussion-between-peter-and-eephyne)